# Limit options for col_type when importing using read_csv

Tags: r, readr, column-types

I am using `readr::read_csv` to import a series of files, then updating with data through and API.  `read_csv` generally does a good job of guessing column type, but seems to default to logical if there isn't data in the first 1000 rows of the file.  If I was always using the same file/ knew which columns the specific file had, I could specify the column type (i.e. using `col_spec= cols( sea_level_pressure_set_1d = col_double(),...`) but since there are multiple files, they don't all have all the columns.
Specifically, it seems that read_csv defaults to logical, which leads to parsing failures.

Is there a way to force read_csv to follow a hierarchy of column types; limit its options to, say just character, double and datetime; or use a .default setting with unknown exceptions?  using the `.default` arguement, it seems that I need to specify all the exceptions, and my problems arise when a file has a different format for an exception.
I would like read_csv to only assign datettime, numeric, and character columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found your solution but may need more details from you to confirm:

**First step:**
You first want to get a col() output for each of your files which you can do manually or use `spec_col()` formula to automatically extract that for you (which I show below).

```
#first create mock dataframe

df1 <- tibble(x=1:3,y=letters[1:3])

df2 <- tibble(a=letters[4:6],b=4:6)

write_csv(df2,file = "df2.csv")
write_csv(df1,file = "df1.csv")

#create file path to pull in files
file_path <- list.files(path=".",pattern="df")

#extract out each file's col_type, set the default, and put it into a list

list <- map(file_path,
            ~spec_csv(.x,
                      col_types = cols(.default=col_character())
                      )
            )
```

This produces the below output:

```
> list
[[1]]
cols(
  x = col_double(),
  y = col_character()
)

[[2]]
cols(
  a = col_character(),
  b = col_double()
)
```

**second step: assign default (optional)**
If you want to assign a default value then you need to use the below for loop (I couldn't figure out how to do this with map but the below works). This basically takes advantage of the special properties of the `cols` class object and assigns a default based on what you assign it. If you assign it a literal character value, the default will become character. If you assign it a literal numeric value, then the default will become numerical.

```
#get the length of your list
x <- seq_along(list)
#loop through each element of the list and assign the <collect_guess> argument a value
for(i in x){
list[[i]][[2]] <- list[[i]][[2]] <- "character"
}
```

This produces the below output:

```
> list
[[1]]
cols(
  .default = col_character(),
  x = col_double(),
  y = col_character()
)

[[2]]
cols(
  .default = col_character(),
  a = col_character(),
  b = col_double()
)
```

**Step3:**
With this variable "list" which stores each's file's `col()` argument, we then need to make a new tibble that pairs the `col()` arguments with the respective files. We can do this with a simple tibble.

```
col_map<- tibble(x=list,y=file_path)
```

**Step 4**
Then use a the `map2_df` function that allows you to pass simultaneously through two vectors (in this case the `col()` arguments (.x) and file path(.y) to a common function `read_csv`

```
map2_df(.x=col_map$x,
.y=col_map$y,
.f = ~read_csv(file=.y,col_types=.x)
)
```

That should save all your files to a new tibble.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think this changes the behavior of readr.  The problem I was facing was `read_csv` defaults to guess_max=1000, and if there is no data in the first guess_max rows, it will default to logical, and parsing will fail for any non 0, 1 , T of F data in that column.  `spec_csv` has identical behavior- see `vignette("column-types", package = "readr")`.  I think I ended up increasing guess_max=inf at the cost of dramatically slowing down the process.  I was looking for a way to avoid having that huge cost.

Comment: It might work to extract the col_types, then search and replace col_logical() in the list with col_character(), which will read any data, then pass the modified list. Depending on the actual type of the columns, this could require some additional data processing after the files are imported.

Comment: It also looks like there current version of readr (version >= 2.0.0) are using a different method for column type guessing (see vignette above), so this might be less of a problem when using the updated version.

Comment: hi, thanks for the response, Then perhaps I misunderstood the original request.  If you don't want the readr to automatically guess the column type you can just manually set the column type with the `col()` function and `as.col_spec`  and save that offline. So either have readr automatically generate the col types for you or you manually set them. Does that make sense?

Comment: I do want readr to automatically guess the column type, because that correctly assigns numeric and datetime classes for most of the columns.  I was working with a series of different files that shared some columns, but some of the files would have 12 columns, others 35, still others 18.  In some cases a few columns would only have data during errors, often halfway through the file. I want readr to guess data type, but if it doesn't find anything, to choose character rather than logical.

Comment: @BrianFisher hey! I think my previous solution didn't work but I worked at it all day and I think I figured it out. Basically we need to assign the <collector_guess> argument in the cols() object type a value. This will then enable a default value. Can you let me know if works? I worked hard on it. If not, can you set up a reproducible example? this will enable me to see if alternative solutions are available.

Comment: I do want readr to automatically guess the column types, but I want it to choose character if there isn't data within guess_max rows.  Several of the files I was working with didn't have one of the sensors on-line for the first several years worth of station data, so no data in the first 100k+ rows. When this is numeric data, readr sees 1000 rows of no data, guesses logical, and throws out all of the data.  If it assigned character data, the data would be read in and could be converted after the fact. I can change the spec manually, but have to know ahead of time what they are.

Comment: Did the new solution in step 2 above help with the default? that should change it so when it doesn't know to choose col_character instead of col_logical.